# Why can't python properly define the variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, variables, key

So I've been stuck wondering why I keep getting a key error, I defined the variables needed (items to store the list of key in the dictionary 'a' (Salad, soup, canapes)) and the dictionary is properly setup. I've managed to narrow it down to the fact that it defines items as the list of keys for the dictionary *a*, but is unable to use it outside of the .join function I used. Why am I getting a key error for items?
Any and all help is appreciated.

```
#Dictionaries#

a = {'SALAD': {'CAPRESE SALAD': 15, 'CEASAR SALAD BITE': 15, 'EGG SALAD': 15},
         'SOUP': {'PUMPKIN COCONUT SOUP': 15, 'TOMATO SOUP': 15, 'CREAMY BROCCOLI SOUP': 15},
         'CANAPES': {'BACON DEVILLED EGGS': 15, 'HALLOUMI DIPPERS': 15, 'MINI PARMA HAM VEGGIE TARTS': 15}}

#obtaining the key from the dictionary 'a'#
class keyretrieval:
    def __init__(self, v, meal):
#setting up title for dialog box#
        title = meal.capitalize()
        items = getList(v)
        inp = simpledialog.askstring(title, 'what would you like for your ' + meal + '?\nwe have ' + ', '.join(items))
#matching user casing to dictionary casing#
        inp = inp.upper()
#other class used that I didn't copy onto here#
        key = Menucheckkey(inp, items)
        self.choice = key

#getting a key from a, appetizer is only used for the dialog box#
akey = keyretrieval(a, 'appetizer')
```

Comment: Your dictionary `a` has no key `'appetizer'`... Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as it's not clear what your code is doing, or your intentions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. " I've managed to narrow it down to the definition of the items variable" Okay, and *what about it*? Do you mean that the *error happens* during that definition? Or do you mean that it has the *wrong value*? Or just what? The code that I see for that is `items = getList(v)`. I don't see `getList`, so I don't know how we are expected to comment on any possible problem with `getList`. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: "I defined the variables and the dictionary is in place" Defined *what* variables? What do you mean that the dictionary is "in place"? "So I've been stuck wondering why I keep getting a key error" In your own words, what do you think a `KeyError` **is**? Why should "defining the variables", and having the dictionary "in place", prevent such an error? I get that you intend to look up `'appetizer'` within the `a` dict. *What do you think the result should be, and why?*

Comment: "other class used that I didn't copy onto here" In your own words, what is a class, and what is it used for? Why is `keyretrieval` a class, rather than a function?

Comment: While you are reading [ask], please note that this is *not a discussion forum*. We are not interested in your age, level of education (or experience with programming), or anything outside of *the question*. "Any help is appreciated" [is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thx for the input. I made my question clearer, and hopefully clear enough. The getList is a module that extracts dictionary keys as a list, and thus it should should extract the keys 'salad', 'soup' and 'canapes'. the goal of this part of the code is to search and match the user's input with one of the three dictionary keys.

Comment: "and thus it should should extract the keys 'salad', 'soup' and 'canapes" Okay, well, **did it**? Is that the problem? "the goal of this part of the code is to search and match the user's input with one of the three dictionary keys" Okay, so *why should that user input have anything to do with* the keys? (Hint: how do you get the input? Did you try to *check* what the input actually is?) Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score -1):

theres no "appetizer" key in the 'a' dictionary

If you want your code to insert a new key when an object is initialized, you can try adding the following to your **init** function

```py
v.update({title : items})
```

Comment: this is *not* how you should update a key-value pair in a dictionary, idiomatically, you would use `v[title] = items`

Comment: had no idea i could just do this. you learn something new every day